# How to make call to database from domain class in grails

Tags: grails

How can we make call to a database view from the domain class?

I have a domain class as

```
class domaintable{

   Integer id
   String abc
   String def

   static mapping = {
      table 'domaintable'
      id column: 'domaintableIdId'
   }
}
```

I need to make a call to another database view like vwAnotherview to make some validations on abc and def. How can I make a call to database for this view from domain class?

Answer (score 0):

Map that to view to a Domain class and use it in a validator. There's nothing stopping you from doing this:

```
static constraints = {
   abc validator: {val, obj ->
      if (!AnotherView.findByThisObject(val).someProperty) return ['somethingsWrong.withAbc']
   }
   def validator: {val, obj ->
      if (!AnotherView.findByThisObject(val).someProperty) return ['somethingsWrong.withDef']
   }
}
```

AnotherView is the object that maps to a view.

To find out more on validators have a look here: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.0/ref/Constraints/validator.html